# Source for praying and repentance on Fast days?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, fast-days, repentance-teshuvah

What is the source for the idea that fast days are not only for fasting and remorse on the past, but also for prayer and repentance for the future?

Comment: For starters, try *Y'sha'yahu* ([58:1-12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1058.htm)) and *Yo'el* ([2:12-14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1402.htm#12)).

Answer (score 2):

[The Mishna in *Taanis 2:1-2*](http://www.emishnah.com/moed2/Ta%27anit/2.pdf) deduces that the main point of the fast is not abstaining from eating, but rather repenting and praying for repentance.

> סדר תענייות כיצד:  מוציאין את התיבה לרחובה של עיר; ונותנין אפר מקלה על
> גבי התיבה, ובראש הנשיא, ובראש אב בית דין, וכל אחד ואחד נוטל ונותן
> בראשו.  והזקן שבהם אומר לפניהם דברי כיבושים--**אחינו, לא נאמר באנשי
> נינווה, וירא האלוהים את שקם ואת תעניתם, אלא "וירא האלו-ים את מעשיהם,
> כי שבו מדרכם הרעה" (יונה ג,י); ובקבלה הוא אומר, "וקרעו לבבכם ואל
> בגדיכם, ושובו אל ה' אלו-יכם:  כי חנון ורחום, הוא--ארך אפיים ורב חסד,
> וניחם על הרעה" (יואל ב,יג).**
>
> ב,ב  **עמדו בתפילה**--מורידין לפני התיבה זקן ורגיל, ויש לו בנים, וביתו
> ריקן, כדי שיהא ליבו שלם בתפילה; ואומר לפניהם עשרים וארבע ברכות--שמונה
> עשרה שבכל יום, ומוסיף עליהן עוד שש
>
> (1) What is the order [of the service] for fast days? The Ark is taken out
> to the square of town . Ash is placed on the Ark and on the head of the
> Nasi and on the head of the Av Bet Din. Everyone else [however,] places ash on
> their own head. The elder among them addresses them with words of
> admonition saying: “**Our brethren, it is not stated regarding the
> people of Ninveh: “And God saw their sackcloth and their fasting,”
> rather: “And God saw their deeds, that they turned from their evil
> ways” (Jonah 3:6). And in the Prophets it is said: And rend your
> hearts and not your garments” (Joel 2:13).**
>
> (2) **They then stood in
> prayer.** They send before the Ark [to serve as hazzan] an Elder, who is
> well conversant [with the prayers], who has children, and whose house
> is empty [of food; another explanation, his house is empty of sin], so
> that